# Is there a way to OR together the WHERE and HAVING clauses in a SQL query?

Tags: sql

Suppose that I have a SQL query

```
SELECT Label1, Label2, SUM(number) as MySum
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Label1, Label2
```

and it gives me some results like

```
Label1 | Label2 | MySum 
-------+--------+------
Foo    | Bar    |   100
Foo    | Baz    |  -100
NotFoo | Bar    |   100
NotFoo | Baz    |  -100
```

I can put a `WHERE` and `HAVING` clause to filter down the results

```
SELECT Label1, Label2, SUM(number) as MySum
FROM MyTable
WHERE Label1 = 'Foo'
GROUP BY Label1, Label2
HAVING MySum > 0
```

and this gives me the results

```
Label1 | Label2 | MySum 
-------+--------+------
Foo    | Bar    |   100
```

The `WHERE` and `HAVING` are `AND`ed implicitly together.

Is there a syntax for something like

```
SELECT Label1, Label2, SUM(number) as MySum
FROM MyTable
WHERE Label1 = 'Foo'
GROUP BY Label1, Label2
OR HAVING MySum > 0
```

giving the results

```
Label1 | Label2 | MySum 
-------+--------+------
Foo    | Bar    |   100
Foo    | Baz    |  -100
NotFoo | Bar    |   100
```

?

I could do

```
SELECT Label1, Label2, SUM(number) as MySum
FROM MyTable
WHERE Label1 = 'Foo'
GROUP BY Label1, Label2

UNION 

SELECT Label1, Label2, SUM(number)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Label1, Label2
HAVING MySum > 0
```

**Disadvantage:** This can be inefficient as the database has to work out the `Foo | Bar | 100` line twice, find that it is a duplicate and then throw it away.

I could also write

```
SELECT Label1, Label2, SUM(number) as MySum
FROM MyTable
WHERE Label1 = 'Foo'
GROUP BY Label1, Label2

UNION ALL

SELECT Label1, Label2, SUM(number)
FROM MyTable
WHERE Label1 <> 'Foo'
GROUP BY Label1, Label2
HAVING MySum > 0
```

**Disadvantage:** It is starting to become less easy to understand at first glance (possibly the least bad disadvantage).

Or

```
SELECT Label1, Label2, SUM(number) as MySum
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Label1, Label2
HAVING MySum > 0
OR Label1 = 'Foo'
```

**Disadvantage:** This will make the database could do a lot of extra work aggregating up lots of non `Foo` labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last of your answers is fine:

```
SELECT Label1, Label2, SUM(number) as MySum
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Label1, Label2
HAVING MySum > 0
OR Label1 = 'Foo'
```

You've said that there is extra work here, but that isn't the case, as you have to do that aggregating to find out if `MySum>0` for the non `Label1='Foo'` rows to determine if they should be included.

Comment: Good point. Could this actually be marginally faster than unions as there will be fewer `Label1='Foo'` checks?

Comment: A single query should be quicker here I think. In any case you're probably looking at micro optimisations unless you're at fairly extreme scale.