# Mixing WHERE and HAVING in an OR operation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database structure (*some fields removed for clarity*):

```
quotes
------
id
name

business_quotes
---------------
id
quote_id
business_id
status
```

For `status` field in `business_quotes` table the possible values are:

- `0` - Quote not answered
- `1` - Quote answered
- `2` - Quote ordered
- `3` - Quote refused

I'd like to retrieve all quotes which have *at least one* order (`status = 2`) **OR** where *all* associated business_quotes records were refused. I can get one or another, with the queries below.

Getting all `quotes` which have an order:

```
SELECT quotes.* 
FROM quotes 
INNER JOIN business_quotes 
ON quotes.id = business_quotes.quote_id 
WHERE business_quotes.status = 2 
GROUP BY quotes.id
```

Getting all `quotes` where all `business_quotes` were refused.

```
SELECT quotes.* 
FROM quotes 
INNER JOIN business_quotes 
ON quotes.id = business_quotes.quote_id 
HAVING SUM(business_quotes.status) = COUNT(business_quotes.id) * 3
```

What I couldn't do was mix the two conditions in a single query.

In some cases it's possible to simply convert the `WHERE` condition into a `HAVING`, like stated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20900476/1128918. But I can't follow the same logic, because the `status` column is not in the `select` statement.

Comment: As a side note, using `SUM(business_quotes.status) = COUNT(business_quotes.id) * 3` as a way to check that all quotes were refused seems like a poor choice to me.  It's likely to confuse anyone who doesn't immediately recall that 3 = refused.  It could cause incorrect results if you add a new status value higher than 3 (because 2+4 = 2*3 ).  I would suggest at least changing it to something like `COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = COUNT(id)`; and it would be even better if you could join with some table that maps the status values to meaningful status names and use those.

Comment: @DaveCosta: I actually started to comment that the HAVING made no sense before realizing what it was doing.  It's definitely an odd way of expressing what it's trying to achieve.

Comment: I agree @DaveCosta. I didn't figure out earlier, but that's a terrible approach. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.  The aggregates in the select are optional.  Essentially you are just using having to query for quotes that have ANY "2" statuses, or have ALL status of value "3".

Disclaimers: not checked for syntax errors, and my usual SQL Language is T-SQL, so it may need tweaking.

```
SELECT 
   quotes.id,
   quotes.name,
   SUM(CASE WHEN business_quotes.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumOrdered,
   SUM(CASE WHEN business_quotes.status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumRefused
FROM 
   quotes 
   INNER JOIN business_quotes ON quotes.id = business_quotes.quote_id 
GROUP BY 
   quotes.id, 
   quotes.name
HAVING 
   SUM(CASE WHEN business_quotes.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
   OR 
   SUM(CASE WHEN business_quotes.status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
   = COUNT(quotes.id)
```

Comment: Thanks Phil Sandler! With a few small changes I could use your suggestions to achieve the results that I wanted. Instead of `SUM` and `CASE`, I'm using `COUNT(IF(business_quotes.status = ?, 1, NULL))`. This way I can use the count of records for each type other for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

That's where UNION is useful:

```
SELECT quotes.* 
FROM quotes 
INNER JOIN business_quotes 
ON quotes.id = business_quotes.quote_id 
WHERE business_quotes.status = 2 
GROUP BY quotes.id
UNION
SELECT quotes.* 
FROM quotes 
INNER JOIN business_quotes 
ON quotes.id = business_quotes.quote_id 
HAVING SUM(business_quotes.status) = COUNT(business_quotes.id) * 3
```

Comment: Hey Russ. I know that in some cases UNION is the best solution and it can even be executed faster than some joins. Maybe I wasn't clear about that when saying "[...] a single query" in my question, because someone can consider two queries united by an UNION as a single query, but I'm avoiding it due some architectural decisions. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If every quote has at least one order, then you can use `not exists` to check whether all orders are of a certain status and `exists` to check whether there is at least one order of a certain status

```
select * from quotes q
where exists (
    select 1 from business_quotes bq
    where bq.status = 2
    and bq.quote_id = q.id
)
or where not exists (
    select 1 from business_quotes bq
    where bq.status <> 3
    and bq.quote_id = q.id
)
```